# Inheritance and overloaded constructors

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm doing some java coding for fun with friends and this came up as one of the problems our book threw at us.

- Build object person with name, age. Simple.
- Extend object person with object profession, which has job name and salary.
- Use two overloaders, one that is given all the information person AND profession
  needs. Simple, user super(blah)
- Second overloader is GIVEN a person object and information to make profession

code looks something along these lines:

Person object

```
public class Person
{

private String name;
private int age;

public Person(String n, int a)
{
    name=n;
    age=a;
}

}
```

Profession object

```
public class Profession extends Person
{

private String jobName;
private int salary;

public Profession(String n, int a, String j, int s)
{
    super(n,a);
    jobName=j;
    salary=s;
}

public Profession(Person p, String j, int s)
{
    //this is where my problem is
}

}
```

I don't know what to do with the person object. Any ideas? I'd appreciate the help! This is not for a grade, just some friends and I getting ahead in class for fun.

Comment: Make getters for the variables then use `super(p.getN(), p.getA());`

Comment: Or else implement `Person(Person p)` constructor

Comment: I like the Person(Person p) idea, but how would I go about that?

As for get variables, that absolutely works! I forgot we were already taught that.

Comment: `public Person (Person p) { this.name = p.name; this.age = p.age; }`

Comment: `Profession` should NOT use `Person`, it is other way around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the more important issue here is that Inheritance is supposed to model the *is-a* relationship. In this scenario a `Profession` *is not* a `Person`, so I don't see any reason why `Profession` would inherit from `Person`.

The more reasonable relationship between `Profession` and `Person` is the *has-a*, People *have* preofessions. A more realistic class structure then is:

```
class Person {
   private String     name;
   private int        age; 
   private Profession profession;

   public Person(String name, int age) { 
      this.name = name;
      this.age  = age;
   }

   public setProfession(Profession p) {
      this.profession = p;
   }
}

class Profession {
   private String job;
   private int salary;

   public Profession(String job, int salary) {
      this.job = job;
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

A different idea that *could* model the inheritance relationship is a `ProfessionalPerson`, but  *I* believe that the modelling above is the most accurate.

```
class ProfessionalPerson extends Person {
   private String job;
   private int salary;

   public ProfessionPerson(String name, int age, String job, int salary) {
      super(name, age);
      this.job = job;
      this.salary = salary;
   } 
}
```

Also, you should always use *descriptive* variable names, so anyone else reading your code can determine which variables mean what. Keep in mind that I left out any error handling and default constructors.

Comment: Yes, that the key thing. Person souldn't be extended with Profession, but if formn must do that (because it's not real life project, but some exercise) then Robin answered.

Comment: @Igor the task asks to "Extend object person with object profession" (i.e. to include profession)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this:

```
public Profession(Person p, String j, int s)
{
    super(p.getName(), p,getAge);//asuming you hava getters for name and salary
    jobName = j;
    salary = s;        
}
```

Comment: It is completely illogical to have `Profession` extending and including `Person` and it is NOT what the tasks asks the OP to do

Answer (score 0):

You may extend `Person` to create `ProfessionalPerson` to have `Profession` (property) too